# What would cause webpack to recursively include every file?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a AMD based project. When I build it with webpack webpack starts loading modules and eventually loads by wildcard/glob recursively for some reason. I'm trying to prevent that.

For example the output from webpack

```
   [0] ./fixme.js 1.9 kB {0} [built]
   [1] ./host/CaptureContext.js 21.1 kB {1} [built] [1 error]
   [2] ./shared/Settings.js 1.2 kB {1} [built]
   [3] ./shared/Extensions.js 1.87 kB {1} [built]
   [4] ./shared/EventSource.js 1.61 kB {1} [built]
   [5] ./shared/Hacks.js 215 bytes {1} [built]
   [6] ./shared/Info.js 122 kB {1} [built]
   [7] ./shared/Utilities.js 8.47 kB {1} [built]
   [8] ./shared/Base.js 2.38 kB {1} [built]
   [9] ./host/Frame.js 16.1 kB {1} [built]
  [10] ./host/StateSnapshot.js 13.1 kB {1} [built]
  [11] ./host/Notifier.js 1.34 kB {1} [built]
  [12] ./host/ResourceCache.js 7.36 kB {1} [built] [1 error]
  [13] ./host/resources/Program.js 10.3 kB {1} [built]
  [14] ./host/Resource.js 5.43 kB {1} [built]
  [15] ./host/ResourceVersion.js 1.75 kB {1} [built]
  [16] ./host/resources/Buffer.js 11.7 kB {1} [built]
  [17] ./host/resources/Framebuffer.js 4.53 kB {1} [built]
  [18] ./host/resources/Renderbuffer.js 2.88 kB {1} [built]
  [19] ./host/resources/Shader.js 2.97 kB {1} [built]
  [20] ./host/resources/Texture.js 29.5 kB {1} [built]
  [21] ./shared/GLConsts.js 31.7 kB {1} [built]
  [22] ./host/resources/VertexArrayObject.js 9.38 kB {1} [built]
  [23] ./host/resources/VertexArrayObjectOES.js 2.12 kB {1} [built]
  [24] ./host/Statistics.js 4.16 kB {1} [built]
  [25] ./host/HostUI.js 10.1 kB {1} [built]
  [26] ./CSSLoader.js 2.33 kB {1} [built]
  [27] . ^\.\/.*$ 128 kB {1} [built] [761 warnings]
  [28] ./buildextensions.sh 0 bytes [optional] [built] [failed]
  [29] ./dependencies/require.js 86.6 kB {1} [optional] [built]
  [30] ./dependencies/reset-context.css 0 bytes [optional] [built] [failed]
  [31] ./dependencies/stacktrace.js 14.8 kB {1} [optional] [built]
  [32] ./dependencies/syntaxhighlighter_3.0.83/LGPL-LICENSE 0 bytes [optional] [built] [failed]
  [33] ./dependencies/syntaxhighlighter_3.0.83/MIT-LICENSE 0 bytes [optional] [built] [failed]
  [34] ./dependencies/syntaxhighlighter_3.0.83/shBrushGLSL.js 2.91 kB {1} [optional] [built]
```

Line 27

```
  [27] . ^\.\/.*$ 128 kB {1} [built] [761 warnings]
```

What causes that? I don't have any references to load modules by wildcard/glob. The program works fine without webpack just using require.js and normal AMD.

`./fixme.js` looks like this

```
require([
     './host/CaptureContext',
     './host/HostUI',
     './CSSLoader',
  ], function(
      captureContext,
      HostUI,
      cssLoader) {
});
```

If I comment out the 2nd 2 lines as in

```
require([
     './host/CaptureContext',
//     './host/HostUI',
//     './CSSLoader',
  ], function(
      captureContext,
      HostUI,
      cssLoader) {
});
```

Then the webpack only includes about 24 modules and doesn't go crazy trying to recursively include the entire tree.

Of course I'll go and start removing things from modules to try to narrow down the issue but my first attempts have not had any luck so I'm looking for ideas what's causing this

Answer (score 0):

The issue is apparently one of the files has this in it.

```
var url = require.toUrl(filename);
```

Webpack sees that line and apparently assumes all files are needed. Commenting out that line fixes is the issue.